# SQL Query to return tier based values

Tags: sql, t-sql, database-design

I have a database with a table for tier based pricing depending on the quantity bought example: (1-10) is $5, (11-15) is $10, 16 is $15, and 17-20 is $20

The table is structured in this way:

number int,
cost int

an example of the table:

## number | cost

1 | 1
2 | 1
3 | 1
4 | 2
5 | 2
6 | 2
7 | 3
8 | 4
9 | 7
10 |7

Is there any way for me to write a query so that i can get these numbers returned in the format min, max, and cost for example running the query on the example above would return:

min|max|cost
-----|-----|----
1 | 10 | 5
11 |15 | 10
16 |16 | 15
17 |20 | 20

Also I am not sure if this is the best structure for such a table. Any and all help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide some sample data of your table? screen shot or something??

Comment: @Hexxed added example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Its rather messy. Just tried it using my Server Management Studio.
**Update:** For better readability.

```
SELECT Mininum.Min, Maximum.Max, Mininum.Cost
FROM 
(
    SELECT MIN([Number]) as 'Min', Cost
    FROM [TestDB].[dbo].[Testing]
    GROUP BY Cost
) as [Mininum]
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT MAX([Number]) as 'Max', Cost
    FROM [TestDB].[dbo].[Testing]
    GROUP BY Cost
) as [Maximum]
ON Mininum.Cost = Maximum.Cost
```